# How to create with nix an environment where Rstudio can be launched

Tags: r, rstudio, nix, nix-flake

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with Rstudio, R, Shiny";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};

        rWrapper=pkgs.rWrapper;
        rstudioWrapper=pkgs.rstudioWrapper;
        rstudioServerWrapper=pkgs.rstudioServerWrapper;
        Rpackages=with pkgs.rPackages;[shiny];

        RwithPackages=   rWrapper.override{ packages =  Rpackages;};
        RStudio-with-my-packages = rstudioWrapper.override{ packages = Rpackages; };


        myDevTools = [
          #qtbase #patch
          RwithPackages
          RStudio-with-my-packages
        ];
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };
      });
}
```

This flake.nix works.

```
nix develop
```

create a virtual environment

but I try to use rstudio, I get this error:

```
 rstudio
```

> TTY detected. Printing informational message about logging
> configuration. Logging configuration loaded from
> '/etc/rstudio/logging.conf'. Logging to ''. qt.qpa.xcb: could not
> connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform
> plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed
> to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, wayland,
> wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, eglfs, linuxfb,
> minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
>
> Aborted

I ve read this [webpage](https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300). I enter this command in my virtual environment:

```
 export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen


 rstudio
```

> TTY detected. Printing informational message about logging
> configuration. Logging configuration loaded from
> '/etc/rstudio/logging.conf'. Logging to ''. QStandardPaths:
> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to
> '/tmp/nix-shell.aeqLGO/runtime-pierre' Fontconfig error: Cannot load
> default config file: No such file: (null) Fontconfig error: No
> writable cache directories Fontconfig error: No writable cache
> directories Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories Fontconfig
> error: No writable cache directories WebEngineContext used before
> QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed. This
> plugin does not support propagateSizeHints() This plugin does not
> support raise() Failed to create OpenGL context for format
> QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options
> QFlagsQSurfaceFormat::FormatOption(), depthBufferSize 24,
> redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1,
> alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior
> QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace
> QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
>
> Aborted

Answer (score 2):

I tried running your Flake locally and it works fine, but I don't have any custom configuration - my system never ran RStudio before and `/etc/rstudio` does not exist. This error is probably caused by RStudio loading non-Nix managed config under `/etc/rstudio`.

You have this in your startup message:

> ```
> Logging configuration loaded from '/etc/rstudio/logging.conf'
> ```

You probably have local configuration using some plugins from another (non-Nix) RStudio installation, but in `nix develop` environment they can't be loaded somehow (apparently some Qt plugin). You can try to:

- Delete or move somewhere else the content of `/etc/rstudio` to avoid configuration issue / conflict and check if it works
- If it does, then enable back previously moved config to bisect the one causing failure

Comment: How is a message describing which configuration file is being used to provide logging information an error?

Comment: (I agree, though, that this does mean the OP has some non-Nix-managed configuration at play)

Comment: Ah indeed, it's not part of an error but "info" on startup. Edited accordingly.